# How to merge a selection of layers using the pre-calculated value option from within the QGIS modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I have a QGIS model that iterates over features in a polygon layer (see screenshot). The outputs are multiple line layers. I need to merge all these line layers. By nature of the model I don’t know how many line layers there will be, but they all have identical names.

I guess I will have to make use of the pre-calculated value option and make an expression that aggregates a list of layers that matches the names of the line layers and then merges them.

How do I go about this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Provding sample data + model could help - otherwise we just have to re-create everything from scratch which takes quite some time and risks to not match your very use case.